# UIButton - rounded corners in highlight state

Tags: iphone, ipad, uibutton, highlight

In the image below the button is being pressed. The shadow is square. How do I make the shadow have rounded edges?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I did it:

1) Subclass the UIButton

2) Change the Layer like this:

```
public class GalleryButton: UIButton
    {

        public GalleryButton (RectangleF frame) : base(frame)
        {
            this.Layer.CornerRadius = 12f;
            this.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
            this.Layer.BorderWidth = 0f;
        }
```

Comment: there is no need to subclass, you can just set the layer properties

Answer (score 0):

I think if you have a transparent png, it works as it is.